# I can't load devtools in R 3.2.0

Tags: r, devtools

I am developping R packages with Rstudio. Until now, I used R 3.1.2 and all worked fine. Recently I have updated R to 3.2.0 version and I have updated the packages too. Now, when loading devtools:

```
> library(devtools)
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
unable to load shared object 'C:/Documents and Settings/cruiz.CREAL/Mis documentos/R/win-library/3.2/git2r/libs/i386/git2r.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  No se encontró el proceso especificado.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’
```

I have reinstalled devtools and git2r with biocLite and with install.packages and it didn't work. This file already exists and it is on this path.

My R session Info:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows XP (build 2600) Service Pack 3

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

1. `remove.packages(c("git2r", "devtools", "rversions"))`.
2. Use the information from my answer on this post -- [R - Error installing Devtools in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219174/r-error-installing-devtools-in-windows/30220882#30220882) to reinstall devtools. This should also reinstall the needed dependencies.