# R - Error installing Devtools in Windows

Tags: r, windows

I'm reasonably new to R, and to stackoverflow, so apologies if I have not provided sufficient detail in my question below.  Happy to provide more info if required

I run Windows 7 Professional (64 bit) and have R version 3.0.2 installed.

When I try to install devtools, I obtain

> library(devtools)

Warning message:

> package ‘devtools’ was built under R version 3.0.3 
>   build_github_devtools()
>
> "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD SHLIB foo.c
>
> gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c foo.c -o foo.o gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o foo.dll tmp.def foo.o -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64 -lR Downloading devtools from https://github.com/hadley/devtools/archive/master.zip
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8yGaPd\devtools-master" --build
>
> - installing to library 'C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8yGaPd/file1afc11f24d1b'
>
> ERROR: dependencies 'rversions', 'git2r' are not available for package
>   'devtools'
>
> - removing 'C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8yGaPd/file1afc11f24d1b/devtools'
>
> Error: Command failed (1)

I've searched for help on dependencies rversions and git2r but no luck so far.

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 2):

This is information about [git2r](http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/web/packages/git2r/index.html)

The following devtools installation information comes from [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools):

Make sure you have a working development environment.

2. Windows: Install [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).
3. Install the release version of devtools from CRAN with `install.packages("devtools")`.

   ## Windows:

   library(devtools)
   build_github_devtools()

   Restart R before continuing

   install.packages("devtools.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")

   Remove the package after installation

   unlink("devtools.zip")