# Failed to install bigrquery on RStudio server

Tags: r, rstudio-server, bigrquery

I recently installed RStudio server on Google Compute Engine and now want to connect to BigQuery. I have successfully installed and loaded packages such as `dplyr` and `ggplot2`, but failed to load `bigrquery` and `devtools`. Running the code snippet below:

```
install.packages("bigrquery")
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/bigrquery")
```

results in this error message:

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’

Loading `bigrquery` separately also results in similar error message:

> Error in library(bigrquery) : there is no package called ‘bigrquery’

I noticed that the installation sent message saying dependencies for the package not available. I didn't get this problem installing and loading `bigrquery` and `devtools` on my RStudio desktop. How can I solve this? I'm working on Windows and launch the RStudio server on Google Chrome.

Comment: You need to install `devtools` first (based on the error)

Comment: I've tried `install.packages('devtools')`. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you try it on a fresh R session.  when you installed the devtools, did you get any error message

Comment: Noticed that you are using `windows`,  Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219174/r-error-installing-devtools-in-windows)

Comment: have you tried `install.packages("devtools", dependencies = T)`?

Comment: Do you get any errors when installing `devtools`, for example from the `openssl` or `gitr` packages? These depend on system libraries which you have to install on the Linux server, including development packages.