# Failure to load git2r and devtools in R

Tags: r, devtools

Somebody else has already asked this question ([I can't load devtools in R 3.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218744/i-cant-load-devtools-in-r-3-2-0)), but the only answer provided by now has not worked for me.

The suggested answer was to remove `git2r` and `devtools`, install `Rtools`, then install `devtools` (which will install the dependent `git2r`), invoke `library(devtools)` and then `build_github_devtools()`.

Although I followed all the steps up to `library(devtools)`, I still get the same error (and thus cannot load `devtools` to proceed further). I have tried loading `git2r` first and receive the same error, from which I conclude that the error is not directly related to `devtools`, but to the `git2r` package. I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: You don't say the error. Also, it is unstated, but I guess it is on Windows.

Comment: Please add the error information as well as the output of sessionInfo().

Comment: I have to apologize for providing incomplete information, it is the first time I post on stackoverflow. Yes, I am on Windows XP, and it seems that this is the reasons, as support for Windows XP has been officially dropped. Error information: "Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/library/git2r/libs/i386/git2r.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’". R version: 3.2.0, under RStudio, 0.98.1062. Many thanks, RA.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load git2r 0.13.1 in R 3.1.2.  The older versions are at:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/git2r

Use command:

```
wget "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/git2r/git2r_0.13.1.tar.gz"
```

(or the correct version for your version of R)

In R, execute command:

```
install.packages('<source directory>/git2r_0.13.1.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: Many thanks, David. I am going to change that computer in 2-3 months, but might still give it a try.