# R - unable to load devtools in R 3.2.0 under Windows XP 32 bit

Tags: r, windows

When I try to load `devtools` in R

```
library(devtools)
```

I get a popup window that reports an `msvcrt.dll` error

> RGui (32-bit) - [R Console]: Rgui.exe - Entry Point Not Found
>
> The procedure entry point _chsize_s could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

and after closing the popup window, R reports the following error

> Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/library/git2r/libs/i386/git2r.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’

Here is the R sessionInfo

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)

Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows XP (build 2600) Service Pack 3

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rversions_1.0.0 RCurl_1.95-4.6  memoise_0.2.1   digest_0.6.8    bitops_1.0-6    XML_3.98-1.1
```

In my search for solutions, I found [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218744/i-cant-load-devtools-in-r-3-2-0) that is very similar and which currently has [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219174/r-error-installing-devtools-in-windows/30220882#30220882) that did not work for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try reinstalling `devtools` with `install.packages(devtools, dependencies = TRUE)`, to be sure to have all dependencies installed.

Comment: I reinstalled setting dependencies=TRUE and still have the issues mentioned above in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I could not install devtools running the latest RStudio and R (as of July 2015) versions on Windows XP SP3.  Apparently the latest version of git2r does NOT support windows XP.

My **workaround** was to install R-3.0.3 and RStudios 0.98.1103. With these versions, install.packages("devtools") works as expected.